# Partial sum of the sequence of combinations of 256

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the following sequence:

$A_n = \frac{256 P_n}{n!}$

Where $256 P_n = \frac {256!}{(256-n)!} $     and $0 < n \leq 128$.

Is there a closed form formula for the partial sum of this sequence, and if there how to calculate it?

Comment: \ge does $\ge$.

Comment: **Hint:** $A_n=\binom{256}{n}$.

Comment: @AnuragA Yes, thanks. I 've noticed that, but I didn't find a closed form formula for a sequence of combinations. What I 've found was only the formula of the summation of all $XC_n$ which is $2^n -1$.

Comment: @HeshamH. Lord Shark the Unknown has already given an elegant solution.

Comment: @AnuragA the page took a while to show the answer. I was writing the comment and there was no answers and when I added it the page refreshed and the answer appeared. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Not very useful, I guess.*

As  Lord Shark the Unknown commented, *"there is no nice formula for general partial sums of the rows of Pascal's triangle"*.

However, there is one which is quite complex
$$S_p=\sum_{n=0}^{p}\frac{256!}{n!(256-n)!}
=\sum_{n=0}^{p}\binom{256}n=2^{256}-\binom{256}{p+1} \, _2F_1(1,p-255;p+2;-1)$$ where appears  [the Gaussian or ordinary hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

Answer (score 1):

I presume you want
$$S=\sum_{n=0}^{128}\frac{256!}{n!(256-n)!}
=\sum_{n=0}^{128}\binom{256}n.$$
This is the sum of the first half of a row of Pascal's triangle, including
the middle term. The sum of a whole row of Pascal's triangle is a power of two
$$\sum_{n=0}^{256}\binom{256}n=2^{256}.$$
The rows of Pascal's triangle are symmetric:
$$\binom{256}n=\binom{256}{256-n}$$
so that
$$S=\sum_{n=128}^{256}\binom{256}n.$$
Then
$$2S=\sum_{n=0}^{128}\binom{256}n+\sum_{n=128}^{256}\binom{256}n
=\sum_{n=0}^{256}\binom{256}n+\binom{256}{128}
=2^{256}+\binom{256}{128}.$$

Comment: I need the sum from n = 1 to N where N is any number between 1 and 128, not only n = 128. I am sorry if my description is not clear enough.

Comment: There is no nice formula for general partial sums of the rows of Pascal's triangle.